# Flutter web Iframe element without height and size in a listview

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web

I have an HtmlElementView widget inside a listview in my flutter web app. I want it to have the same size as the size of its contents. also am putting a flutter widget under it. Like

```
listview(
children:<widget>[
HtmlElementView(),
Text(),
Footer(),
]
)
```

So far when I try to do this I get an exception from the rendering Library. Is there a way to achieve what I want to do?

Comment: What exception are you getting? Usually `shrinkWrap` property of listView widget should solve this issue.

Comment: I have tried shrinkwrap and it doesn't work. Seems it needs a specific height